# Sort Kendo UI grid by Checkbox status?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo grid in a MVC project. The first column is a checkbox which defines by ClientTemplate:

```
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Checked).ClientTemplate(@"<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />").Width(50).Title("");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName); 
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName); 
        columns.Bound(c => c.Company);  
    })
```

What I want to have is: before click the header, it looks like the 1st screen shot. then make changes to the checkbox, click the header again, it will sort the row by the checkbox status, see screen shot 2.

I tried to set the 1st column sortable, but all others not sortable. Still not works. I think it is because when the data binds to the grid, c.Checked is always false. Now, if we click the checkbox, it does not change the value of that. That's why the sort does not work for this column.

How to make this work?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Putting `.Sortable(true)` after a column won't do anything unless sorting is enabled on the entire grid. Make the entire grid sortable and then just disable sorting for unwanted columns:

```
.Columns(c => 
{ 
  c.Bound(...).Width(..).Title(....);
  c.Bound(...).Width(..).Title(....).Sortable(false);
})
.Sortable()
```